# Exporting with .fbx does weird stuff for me

Tags: export, normals, geometry, .fbx

I've been racking my brain and searching the internet, but maybe someone here can help me out!

I have this object that has an image texture on it. And when I export it to FBX (with copy and embed textures) it exports like this:
[image: Object after .fbx export]

This is the object before I export it:

[image: The normals looks fine right?]

I'd love to hear what I'm doing wrong or if there is something I haven't thought about.
Cheers,
Lo